# multiple classes with conditional statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have multiple classes in my code around 10 times more than here along with few classes that serve the same purpose when clicked.
I rarely code in javascript, all I want is a better way to achieve this than what I got here in the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".item1, .item2, .item3").click(function(event) {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
     if (myClass === "item1"){
    document.write("Option 1"); // do something else
    }
    else if (myClass === "item2"){
    document.write("Option 2"); //do something else
    }
    else if (myClass === "item3"){
    document.write("Option 3"); // same thing as option 1
    }
    else document.write("Incorrect");
  });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="item1">item 1</div>
<div class="item2">item 2</div>
<div class="item3">item 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to watch which item is clicked from a group?

I think the approach is wrong, both in the HTML structure as well as in the logic with the DOM and Javascript. 
You can put you items(HTML) inside a parent and use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) on the parent.

Afterwards, check the option based on the clicked element.

```js
$("#parent").click( function(event) {

    var elementClass  = event.target.className,
        $output       = $("#output");

    //  NOTE: We asume that the Element has one class
    switch (elementClass) {
      case "item1":
        $output.text("Option 1");
        break;
      case "item2":
        $output.text("Option 2");
        break;
      case "item3":
        $output.text("Option 3");
        break;
    }

});
```

```css
#parent > * {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  display : inline-block;
  background : red;
}

#parent > div:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left : 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="parent">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>

<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I needed, now my codes are lengthy but organized, that solved my issue completely. although there are many ways to go about it but I guess, I will stick to this.

Comment: From my experience, it's best to present a larger context in order for others to fully understand the situation. This way, you may find that there are other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a persistent object, whose properties are class names and values are the associated text for each class name - it's pretty concise, and adding more options is trivial, you just need to define the key-value pairs:

```js
const classOptions = {
  item1: 'Option 1',
  item2: 'Option 2',
  item3: 'Option 3',
};

$(".item1, .item2, .item3").click(function(event) {
  const optionText = classOptions[$(this).attr("class")];
  document.write(optionText || 'Incorrect');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">item 1</div>
<div class="item2">item 2</div>
<div class="item3">item 3</div>
```

Also, rather than `$(".item1, .item2, .item3").click`, you might find it easier if, if possible, you put a click handler on the *parent* of the items - that way, you don't have to write out each individual class name in the selector, which would be quite a pain if you have tons of classes:

```js
const classOptions = {
  item1: 'Option 1',
  item2: 'Option 2',
  item3: 'Option 3',
};

$(".container").click(({ target }) => {
  const optionText = classOptions[$(target).attr("class")];
  document.write(optionText || 'Incorrect');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">item 3</div>
</div">
```

Comment: Well that did sorted out my extra mess, but what if it's not just a key-value, class and text values, but calling another function?

Comment: Then have the values be the function name, and then use bracket notation to look up the function in another object. eg use `fnName` instead of `optionText` and then `fns[fnName]()`. You might also consider putting all the functions directly inside the `classOptions` object, if that's a viable possibility

Comment: Well that certainly was a great help for a newbie like me and it looks neat as well, I would mark this as the best answer for now while I get to implement the fresh ideas into my code. please forgive me for not posting all the code, it was a complete mess and all too confusing with so many statements that I had start fresh. I am glad that I finally took the step to ask the community and wasn't disappointed.